# Mssql still bulk insert type mismatch errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hy,

I am using bulk insert to insert records from a csv file in database. On some files i have a field wich is `type mismatch or invalid character` but the SQL inserts the other rows except that one.

Ex : file with 7334 rows (1 row is type mismatch) -> 7333 rows inserted.

Is this the normal behavior of SQL or what is wrong.

Comment: Yes - it's normal behaviour.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, do you have more information about this behaviour? I have never seen it before, when I have a mismatch nothing is inserted.

Comment: I dont have any other information because i do just a simple BULK INSERT with nothing special

Comment: @123onetwothree it is due to data type you want to insert. it is not compliance with the column type you mention.

Comment: @randytan the field is bigint and the data in the csv is like 00:12:2A:3F

Comment: Bulk-insert uses batches, if a batch fails, and you don't have an explicit transaction, only the failed batch will be rolled back. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

Comment: but how can i enforce that ? i never happened to me again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the behaviour expected when you try to insert a data type that is different (in most cases) to the field(s) you are inserting data to. For an instance, you will get a type mismatch error if you try to insert a text value to a integer field.

bigint column won't let you insert a value like '00:12:2A:3F'. First check your source data and verify whether that column actually has the value '00:12:2A:3F'. If not, it could be the reason i explain in the note below. If the value is accurate with the source data you might have to change the column definition to a appropriate datatype such as varchar().

Unless you have forced **CHECK_CONSTRAINTS** Sqlserver will skip the erroneous records and inserts the other complying records. If you want the insert to fail on error (such as type mismatch) use **CHECK_CONSTRAINTS** on your bulk insert stament like this:

```
BULK INSERT DB.dbo.Test 
FROM '.....' 
WITH ( CHECK_CONSTRAINTS, .......)
```

**Note:**
*One thing to keep in mind is the data itself isn't polluted with field delimiters. For an instance if your fields are seperated by ',' delimiter and one of your fields has a comma within the data (a text column like 'comments' may have commas in them), SQL server think a new column start there and break the field causing the other column to be mis-aligned. That could be a reason for your type mismatch.*

Comment: I understand that it's normal to throw an error but why does it insert the correct rows and only skip the row with the error.

Comment: Unless you have forced CHECK_CONSTRAINTS Sqlserver will skip the erroneous records and inserts the other complying records. If you want the insert to fail on error (such as type mismatch) use CHECK_CONSTRAINTS on your bulk insert stament like this:

BULK INSERT DB.dbo.Test
FROM '.....'
WITH (
    **CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,**
    .......)

Comment: no worries, i've updated the main answer with the code snippet.